How do compilers/parsers support/detect language versions?
I've been trying to find some material to read on how compilers/parsers are able to detect different versions of a language they're designed to compile/parse, and how they handle conflicts between the different versions.
So far my search has not turned up anything aside from Semantic Predicates from ANTLR.
However, I intend to write my own parser and I would like to know if there are any general strategies that are applied when parsers aim to support multiple language versions.
In particular I'd like to know:

How parsers can determine a language version.
How to handle conflicts between language versions.

If at all possible please provide some examples of open source parsers/compilers that have these capabilities.

they don't, you pass flag to indicate what version should be used, or they just assume latest version

@IłyaBursov How does that work with interpreters? For instance V8? How do they support multiple versions? Since there's no way to pass a version there afaik.

interpreters are the same - they assume latest version, as soon as programming languages usually backward compatible, it means that latest version of compiler/interpreter can understand any previous versions or it will fail with some syntax error and then you have to indicate another version as flag/argument

@IłyaBursov Very useful thank you. Would you mind posting it as an answer so I can mark this question solved?

Answered in the comments below the question.
Adding this answer to close the question.
